# How to convert number to word in ruby without using any gem?

Tags: ruby

I have a  number say 100 i want it converted into one hundred in word.similary for floating point say 0.0 is zero and 3.4 to three point four

Comment: Why won't you use a gem? Because this is an exercise? Or a requirement at work?

Comment: i was trying to without gem how can we do it.

Comment: @VedprakashSingh : You can test my answer it may helps you

Comment: @VedprakashSingh: If you are trying to do something, then on Stack Overflow it is normal to show the code that you are trying, and ask questions about what you need to do next, or why it is not working. Please do not just ask for someone else to do it for you. Also, you could just read the code in one of the gems . . . . they are open source.

Answer (score 2):

There are many gems available which convert number to word:

- **[gem 'to_words'](https://github.com/taimur-akhtar/to_words)**
- **[humanize](https://github.com/radar/humanize)**
- **[numbers_and_words](https://rubygems.org/gems/numbers_and_words)**

But as you don't want to use gem I found something like (without any gem):

```
class Fixnum
 def english_word
  @h = { 0=>"zero", 1=>"One", 2=>"Two", 3=>"Three", 4=>"Four", 5=>"Five",6=>"six", 7=>"seven", 8=>"Eight", 9=>"Nine",10=>"Ten",11=>"Eleven",12=>"Twelve", 13=>"Thirteen",14=>"Fourteen",15=>"Fifteen", 16=>"Sixteen",17=>"Seventeen",18=>"Eighteen", 19=>"Nineteen",20=>"Twenty",30=>"Thirty", 40=>"Fourty",50=>"Fifty",60=>"Sixty",70=>"Seventy", 80=>"Eighty",90=>"Ninty" }
  @i=0
  @array=[]
  @result=""a
  if self > 99
    str_num=self.to_s #@num.to_s
    str_num_len=str_num.length
    str_full_num=str_num.insert(0,"0"*(11-str_num_len))
    str_full_num=str_num.insert(8,"0")
    str_full_num.scan(/../) { |x|  @array<<x }
    6.times do
    self.def_calc
    @i+=1
    end
  else
     if self > 9
        puts (self.proc_double_dig((self/10)*10)) + (self.proc_single_dig(self%10))
     else
       if self > 0
         puts self.proc_single_dig(self)
       else
         return "AMOUNT NOT KNOWN or NILL"
       end
     end
  end
  end

  def def_calc
    case @i
      when 0
        str=self.proc_unit(@array[@i])
        if (str.scan(/\w+/)).length!=0
             then str=str+ "hundred & "
              @result=@result+str
        end
      when 1
        str=self.proc_unit(@array[@i])
        if (str.scan(/\w+/)).length!=0
             then str=str+ " Crore, "
             @result=@result+str
        end
      when 2
        str=self.proc_unit(@array[@i])
        if (str.scan(/\w+/)).length!=0
             then str=str+ " Lakh, "
             @result=@result+str
        end
      when 3
        str=self.proc_unit(@array[@i])
        if (str.scan(/\w+/)).length!=0
             then str=str+ " Thousand, "
             @result=@result+str
        end
      when 4
        str=self.proc_unit(@array[@i])
        if (str.scan(/\w+/)).length!=0
             then str=str+ " Hundred, "
             @result=@result+str
        end
      when 5
        str=self.proc_unit(@array[@i])
        if (str.scan(/\w+/)).length!=0
             then str=str+ ". "
             @result=@result+str
        end
        print @result.sub(/..$/,"")
    else
   end
  end

  def proc_unit(x)
    if x.to_i>0
      if x.to_i<=10
        return self.proc_single_dig(x.to_i)
      else
        if x.to_i<=20
        return self.proc_double_dig(x.to_i)
        else
        return (self.proc_double_dig((x.to_i/10)*10)) + (self.proc_single_dig(x.to_i%10))
        end
     end
    end
  return ""
  end

  def proc_double_dig(z)
    if z==0
      return ""
    else
      return @h[z]
    end
 end

  def proc_single_dig(y)
    if y==0
      return ""
    else
      return @h[y]
    end
  end
protected :def_calc, :proc_unit, :proc_double_dig,
  :proc_single_dig

end

puts 453645445.english_word

#FourtyFive Crore, Thirtysix Lakh, FourtyFive Thousand,Four Hundred,FourtyFive
```

Reference Taken from : https://raveendran.wordpress.com/2009/05/29/ruby-convert-number-to-english-word/

I hope it helps you :)

Answer (score 2):

This is what i have found solution . i hope this will help others.

```
def in_words(int)
  numbers_to_name = {
      10**18 => "quintillion", 10**15 => "quadrillion", 10**12 => "trillion",
      10**9 => "billion", 10**6 => "million", 1000 => "thousand", 100 => "hundred", 
      90 => "ninety", 80 => "eighty", 70 => "seventy", 60 => "sixty", 50 => "fifty",
      40 => "forty", 30 => "thirty", 20 => "twenty", 19=>"nineteen",
      18=>"eighteen", 17=>"seventeen", 16=>"sixteen", 15=>"fifteen",
      14=>"fourteen", 13=>"thirteen", 12=>"twelve", 11 => "eleven", 10 => "ten", 
      9 => "nine", 8 => "eight", 7 => "seven", 6 => "six", 5 => "five",
      4 => "four", 3 => "three", 2 => "two", 1 => "one"
    }
  str = ""
  numbers_to_name.each do |num, name|
    if int == 0
      return str
    elsif int.to_s.length == 1 && int/num > 0
      return str + "#{name}"      
    elsif int < 100 && int/num > 0
      return str + "#{name}" if int%num == 0
      return str + "#{name} " + in_words(int%num)
    elsif int/num > 0
      return str + in_words(int/num) + " #{name} " + in_words(int%num)
    end
  end
end

def words_from_numbers number 
  fix = number.to_i == 0 ? "zero" : in_words(number.to_i).strip.gsub('hundred ','hundred and ')
  frac = number - number.to_i == 0 ? "" : " point one"
  fix + frac

end
```